# Proving a well-known formula regarding adj(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The adjugate of a matrix $A$ is defined as
$$
(\mathrm{adj}(A))_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}M_{ji}(A)
$$
where $M_{ji}(A)$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$ after row $j$ and column $i$ have been removed. It is well-known that
$$
A\,\mathrm{adj}(A) = \mathrm{adj}(A)A = \det(A) I
$$
Therefore, if $A$ is invertible, we get the famous formula $A^{-1} = \det(A)^{-1}\mathrm{adj}(A)$. There is also a well-known expansion of $A$ using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, that looks like this:
$$
p_0 I + p_1 A + p_2 A^2 + \dots + p_n A^n = 0
$$
where the $p_i$ are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$.
I have seen it written in many places (wikipedia, planetmath, textbooks) that the following also holds:
$$
\mathrm{adj}(A) = -(p_1 I + p_2 A + \dots + p_n A^{n-1})
$$
where the $p_i$ are the same as in the previous equation. It is easy to prove this formula in the case where $A$ is invertible by applying the identities given above together with the fact that $p_0 = \det(A)$. However, I think the adjugate expansion still holds when $A$ is not invertible... how do I prove it for such a case?

Comment: The function $A \mapsto \mathrm{adj}(A)$ is continuous, and the functions $A \mapsto p_k(A)$ (the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial) are continuous. The set of invertible matrices is dense, hence a continuity argument shows that the formula must hold for singular matrices.

Comment: While this argument works for real matrices, I would like a proof that holds for matrices whose entries belong to a general commutative ring. This argument would fail if applied for example to matrices of integers.

Comment: I think the fastest way to prove this is by noting that $p_k$ is the sum of all $(n-k)$-minors of $A$.

Comment: Beware! you have $p_0=\det(A)$ only if your definition of characteristic polynomial is $P_A(x)=\det(A-xI)$, but in this case your characteristic polynomial is not monic. If you define instead $P_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$, then your characteristic polynomial is monic, with constant coefficient equal to $\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$.

Comment: @walcher, I am aware of the formula you make reference to, but I fail to see how it can help me with the proof.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, yes you are correct. $p_0 = \pm \det(A)$ depending on which definition of the characteristic polynomial you are using.

Comment: See this excellent [expository paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf) from Keith Conrad, where it is shown how to prove general identities by specializing to real or complex numbers.

Comment: You can find an elementary proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345517/why-is-it-true-that-mathrmadjaa-deta-cdot-i/345949#345949).

Comment: Answered in MO: [Expressing adj(A) as a polynomial in A?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32133/expressing-adja-as-a-polynomial-in-a)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. The Conrad paper was very interesting. Thanks @MatemáticosChibchas.

Comment: aha! seems I asked this question some years ago in MO. Thank you @user1551.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of having an answer: the OP had asked this question on MO before and got a number of good answers there. See [Expressing adj(A) as a polynomial in A?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32133/expressing-adja-as-a-polynomial-in-a)