# Proving $adj(A)A=det(A)I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem which uses the fact that $adj(A)A=det(A)I$, where I is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ for a field $\mathbb{F}$.

Could you indicate me a quick way of proving this or to a reference proving it ?

And is is true for a matrix with coefficients over any commutative ring ? I would guess so because C-H is true for any commutative ring. In this case, is the proof the same ?

Thanks

Comment: See [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345517/why-is-it-true-that-mathrmadjaa-deta-cdot-i) answers.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Is the link you provided sufficient to answer the part of the question concerned with arbitrary commutative rings? If not I would not count this as duplicate.

Comment: @Thomas the proofs there are valid also for commutative rings.