# Why in the proof of $A\cdot Adj(A)=Det(A)\cdot I_n$ entires not on the diagonal are zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have [read the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345517/why-is-it-true-that-mathrmadjaa-deta-cdot-i). I do not get why the entires that are not on the diagonal are equal to zero, or why the following part of [the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345517/why-is-it-true-that-mathrmadjaa-deta-cdot-i) is true:

If $k\neq \ell$

$$(A\cdot\hat A)_{k\ell}=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+\ell}a_{ki} \det A(\ell\mid i)=0$$

Comment: It's the determinant of the matrix you get when in $A$ you replace the $\ell$-th row with the $k$-th. The resulting matrix has two identical rows, hence the determinant is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so there is an action of replacing a row? It do not derive from the formula?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Interpret the formula bearing [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) in mind.

Comment: @DanielFischer you have said "replace the ℓ-th row with the k-th. The resulting matrix has two identical rows" but according to the formula we take the entry $a_ki$ for a chosen row $k$ and multiply it with the determinant of the matrix $A$ when removing the ℓ-th row and i-th column.
Why are there two identical rows?

Comment: That's not quite what I said. If we compute the $(k,\ell)$-component of $A\cdot \operatorname{Adj}(A)$, we get an expression. And we get the same expression when we use Laplace expansion (by the $\ell$-th row) to compute the determinant of the matrix we get when we replace the $\ell$-th row of $A$ with the $k$-th row. (It's not quite coincidental that we get the same expression.) If $k = \ell$, then we get $A$ again, hence on the diagonal of the product we have $\det A$. If $k\neq \ell$, we get a matrix with two identical rows, hence with determinant $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry, I don't get it, according to Laplace expansion we remove a row and a column, so how can we say that we replace the ℓ-th row of A with the k-th row

Comment: Laplace expansion by the $\ell$-th row gives you $$\det B = \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{\ell + i} b_{\ell i}\det B(\ell \mid i).$$ Now, if $B$ is the matrix you obtain from $A$ by replacing the $\ell$-th row with the $k$-th, then $B(\ell \mid i) = A(\ell \mid i)$, and also $b_{\ell i} = a_{k i}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so we first create the $B$ with two identical rows and then use the Laplace expansion?

Comment: Hypothetically. As a Gedankenexperiment. We don't actually do that. But that way we see that, and why, we have $A\cdot \operatorname{Adj} A = (\det A)\cdot I$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the $3\times 3$ case
$$
\underbrace{\left[\matrix{\color{red}{a_{11}} & \color{red}{a_{12}} & \color{red}{a_{13}}\\ \color{blue}{a_{21}} & \color{blue}{a_{22}} & \color{blue}{a_{23}}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}\right]}_{A}\cdot
\underbrace{\left[\matrix{A_{11} & A_{21} & A_{31}\\ A_{12} & A_{22} & A_{32}\\
A_{13} & A_{23} & A_{33}}\right]}_{\text{adj}(A)}.
$$
If you multiply the first row with the first column you get exactly the determinant expansion along the first row
$$
\color{red}{a_{11}}A_{11}+\color{red}{a_{12}}A_{12}+\color{red}{a_{13}}A_{13}=\left|\matrix{\color{red}{a_{11}} & \color{red}{a_{12}} & \color{red}{a_{13}}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}\right|=\det(A).
$$
Now if you multiply the second row with the first column you get
$$
\color{blue}{a_{21}}A_{11}+\color{blue}{a_{22}}A_{12}+\color{blue}{a_{23}}A_{13}
$$
which in the same way can be interpreted as the determinant expansion along the first row, but for what matrix? Well, the cofactors are built of the elements of the second and third rows of $A$, so those rows remain unchanged, and the first row must be made of the blue elements, since it is them who replace the red elements in the formula above,  hence
$$
\color{blue}{a_{21}}A_{11}+\color{blue}{a_{22}}A_{12}+\color{blue}{a_{23}}A_{13}=
\left|\matrix{\color{blue}{a_{21}} & \color{blue}{a_{22}} & \color{blue}{a_{23}}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}}\right|.
$$
But this matrix has first two rows being equal, which means that the determinant is *zero*.

P.S. For other rows and columns the idea is exactly the same. The second row times the second column and the third row times the third column will be the determinant expansion along the second and the third rows, respectively, and give $\det(A)$. All other combinations give zero since there are two equal rows in the corresponding determinant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only point that I do not get is why "first row must be made of the blue elements"

Comment: This is how the expansion works. Compare with the red elements above. The blue elements replace the red ones.

Comment: this is what we get: $$
\color{blue}{a_{21}} \left|\matrix\\ a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{32} & a_{33}}\right|+\color{blue}{a_{22}}\left|\matrix{\color{blue}\\ a_{21} &  & a_{23}\\
a_{31} &  & a_{33}}\right|+\color{blue}{a_{23}}\left|\matrix{\color{blue}\\ a_{21} &  & a_{22}\\
a_{31} &  & a_{32}}\right|$$

Comment: Minus in the middle term.

Comment: $$
\color{blue}{a_{21}} \left|\matrix\\ a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{32} & a_{33}}\right|-\color{blue}{a_{22}}\left|\matrix{\color{blue}\\ a_{21} &  & a_{23}\\
a_{31} &  & a_{33}}\right|+\color{blue}{a_{23}}\left|\matrix{\color{blue}\\ a_{21} &  & a_{22}\\
a_{31} &  & a_{32}}\right|=a_{21}(a_{22}a_{33}-a_{23}a_{32})-a_{22}(a_{21}a_{33}-a_{23}a_{31}+a_{23}(a_{21}a_{32}-a_{22}a_{31})=0$$

Comment: I got it, "must be made of the blue elements" it because those are the entry we multiply the matrix that was left (2 by 2)

Comment: Right. Now the last step is to see the same principle for the $n\times n$ case. (This is what @DanielFischer was saying in the comments).