# Prove that $A^{-1}=\frac{adj(A)}{|A|}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Prove that $$A^{-1}=\frac{adj(A)}{|A|}$$

Can the above condition be proved without actually putting values and solving it. I consulted many books. Only way they proved it is by solving it by putting values and then proving that $A^{-1}A=I_n$.

Comment: All the property of adjoint of matrix relates to this theorem

Comment: What do you mean "putting values"?  You need to, in some fashion, show $$\operatorname{adj}(A)\,A = |A|\cdot I_n$$

Comment: This is done by using LEFT HAND SIDE=RIGHT HAND SIDE. I just want to know whether it can be proved by theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Brian Moehring, first show that $$(\text{adj}A)\cdot A=I_n\cdot |A|=A\cdot (\text{adj}A)$$ You can check the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/345517/782505).

Now, we've $$A\left(\frac{1}{|A|}\text{adj}A\right)=I_n=\left(\frac{1}{|A|}\text{adj}A\right)A$$

By the definition of inverse of a matrix,

> A square matrix $A$ of order $n$ is invertible if there exists a square matrix $B$ if the same order such that $$AB=I_n=BA$$
> In such case, we say that the inverse of $A$ is $B$ and we write, $A^{-1}=B$.

We get $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{|A|}\text{adj}A$$